# Lighthouse user-flows integration with Playwright

Tags: puppeteer, performance-testing, playwright, lighthouse, playwright-test

Lighthouse user flows are implemented to work with Puppeteer api. I'm trying to use it in a Playwright project, but it's not supporting. Is there a way to do this without interferring with the lighthouse core packages?

This is the startFlow function in lighthouse. It uses Puppeteer's Page, which is very different from Playwright Page as I understand.

`export function startFlow(page: LH.Puppeteer.Page, options?: LH.UserFlow.Options | undefined): Promise<UserFlow>;`

I want to start the flow with a Playwright Page object, interact with the UI and then generate a report.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is possible in theory, though I don't know how much work it would take. Some starting points:
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/discussions/13326
- https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10068
- https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/playwright-lighthouse